# How do I create a redirect URL in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, http-redirect

I'm new to the world of IIS in terms of redirects and have been tasked with setting up a redirect for a portion of our site.

> The URL I need to redirect is brandview.auditedmedia.com and I need it
>   to go to https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view
>
> The trick is we can have a URL with a QueryString such as
>   brandview.auditedmedia.com/memberNumber=423524 and that URL should NOT
>   be redirected.
>
> Also, the scheme of brandview.auditedmedia.com does not matter.  Both
>   HTTP and HTTPS should redirect.

So I'm not sure should I be doing this in IIS or as a RouteMap in the app?
If I should be doing this in IIS can someone point me to either an article or give an example of what I need to do?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Please, specify version of your Windows and IIS web server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add URL rewrite rule on the server level. Use conditions to prevent redirection for requests with non-empty query string string. 
For your case it is necessary to add the following rule:

```
<rule name="brandview redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^brandview\.auditedmedia\.com$" negate="false" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

There is [detailed instruction](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) on your question. Note, the rule must be created in *system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules* section of *%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config* file.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm waiting for our tech department to install URL Rewrite Module so I can use your answer.

Comment: I put the changes you listed above in web.config for my Brandview App inside of system.webServer element and I get a 500 error.  I know that the redirect URL is valid.  I decided to just add the rule to web.config rather than proceed through URL Rewrite Module.  Is there something else that I need on my server or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The 500 error says The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.  I'm looking at the code and it doesn't look like any XML is malformed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but I ran the code from VS on my machine and changed the HTTP_HOST to be localhost:42424 and it worked as expected.

Comment: Is your server hosting for brandview.auditedmedia.com?

Comment: Include conditions step by step. In first, try add HTTP_HOST condition. And when requests to brandview.auditedmedia.com will be redirected,  add condition by query string.

Comment: Also you can add new web site with host header value brandview.auditedmedia.com and setup URL rewrite rule on this node. Before URL rewrite rule settings sure that status of brandview.auditedmedia.com is 200 (OK).

Comment: This walkthrough may be useful too: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Yes we host our own site.

Comment: When I attempt to use just HTTP_HOST condition, I get the error 500.

Comment: Ok, I have been back. Is there web site node for _brandview.auditedmedia.com_ on your IIS web server?

Comment: Yes Brandview is it's own separate node on the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I got the pattern fixed (see below) and though all the pattern matching works properly in URL Rewrite Module (using test button and putting in different URLs), it still isn't working properly when I attempt to go to the site.  The server just continues with serving the page and not redirecting.

```
<rewrite>
     <globalRules>
        <rule name="brandview redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(https?:\/\/)?brandviewdev\.auditedmedia\.com$" negate="false" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add URL rewrite rule using GUI. Before you start make sure that both of the direct HTTP-requests to *brandview.auditedmedia.com* and *https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view* returns status 200 (OK).

1. Open IIS Manager by prompting `inetmgr` command.
2. Select **brandview** web site in the Connections pane and open **URL Rewriting** feature.
3. Create new empty rule using **Add rule(s)...** action.
4. Within the **Edit Inbound Rule** dialog, enter the following:

   - Name: *Redirect to auditedmedia.com*;
   - Requested URL: *Matches the Pattern*;
   - Using: *Regular expressions*;
   - Pattern: *.**;
   - Action type: *Redirect*;
   - Redirect URL: *https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view*.
   - Append query string: *false*;
   - Redirect type: *See Other (303)*;
5. Save the rule by clicking Apply on the **Actions** pane.
6. Make sure that request to *brandview.auditedmedia.com* will be redirected to  https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view.
7. Repeat steps 1, 2 and select *Redirect to auditedmedia.com* rule.
8. Execute action **Add condition(s)...** with following:

   - Condition input: *{QUERY_STRING}*;
   - Check if input string: *Does Not Matches the Pattern*;
   - Pattern: *.+*;
   - Ignore case: *true*.
9. Push **OK** button.

As result, all requests to brandview.auditedmedia.com with empty query string will be redirected to https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view page. After testing you can change redirect type to 301.

Comment: I did all of that and now when I type in brandviewdev.auditedmedia.com it redirects correctly, but if I enter brandviewdev.auditedmedia.com/?memberNumber=4235245 it doesn't redirect (like it should), but the execution of the page stops and the data doesn't get loaded.  If I disable the rule, then the redirect to https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view doesn't occur, but if I make a call with the query string, that code works.  Here is my xml from web.config

Comment: <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Brandview Redirect" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

Comment: If you use local redirect rule, make sure that global rules are disabled. Also you can try to set other temporary redirect type: 302, 303 or 307.
I would like to test redirection online. What is your time zone?

Comment: I'm in U.S. Central Time Zone.  Currently though I'm testing this on a development server, because if I do it on the production server our clients can't get to the site when using the Query String and that would be an problem.

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

After trying different combinations I finally got the redirect to work correctly and to be honest, I'm not sure how.  Here is my config

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Brandview Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />

                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://auditedmedia.com/data/media-intelligence-center/brand-view" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="brandviewdev\.auditedmedia\.com" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```